# How to pass (different) generics to varags?

Tags: scala

I have a container class

```
object OptimisationVariable {

  implicit class OptimisationVariableSeq[B](seq: Seq[OptimisationVariable[B]]) {
    def extract[A: ClassTag](variable: (OptimisationVariable[B] => A)): DenseVector[A] =
      DenseVector(seq.map(variable).toArray)
  }

}

final case class OptimisationVariable[B: ClassTag](startposition: B,       
                                                   startlearningrate: Double)
```

which I want to pass to my algorithm:

```
class MyAlgorithm(optimisationVariable: OptimisationVariable*)
```

but I get the error that OptimisationVariable takes a type parameters. That makes sense. However I want to pass be able to pass different kinds  of parameter. Since `optimisationVariable` is going to be a `Seq`, I am not sure how I am supposed to go about this. `B` is going to be an `Int` or a `Double`. E.g.

```
new MyAlgorithm(OptimisationVariable(1, 2.0), OptimisationVariable(3.0, 4.0))
```

Later I want to decide what to do, depending on whether its an `Int` or a `Double`.

Comment: Not possible with vararg. You can have a look at shapeless

Comment: @cchantep: I thought this might be possible with view bounds or something like that (though they seem to be deprecated).

Comment: @cchantep: Do you know how to do it with shapeless for this case?

Comment: it has never been possible, as any value of the vararg must have the same type, which "at best" leads to erasure `OptimisationVariable[_]`; https://www.scala-exercises.org/shapeless/polymorphic_function_values

Comment: @Make42 you can store an Int inside a Double.

Comment: "Deciding later what to do" is exactly the kind of thing they invented perl ad ruby, and python for. Why are you writing this in scala?

Comment: Did you see HList? https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-lists

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to restrict `B` at all, using existential type is OK:

```
final case class OptimisationVariable[B: ClassTag](
    startposition: B,
    startlearningrate: Double
)
case class MyAlgorithm(optimisationVariable: OptimisationVariable[_]*)
// and then
MyAlgorithm(OptimisationVariable(1, 1.0), OptimisationVariable(2, 1.1))
```

If you are going to restrict them by some upper bound, throw in some typeclasses and you are still good.

In case you are inspired to try shapeless, as suggested by the comments above, here's a good starting book (Fret not! It's short and practical): [shapeless-guide](https://github.com/underscoreio/shapeless-guide/blob/develop/dist/shapeless-guide.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your example a bit, so as I understood, essentially you want this:

```
case class Ov[A](start: A, degree: Double)
case class MyAlg[L <: HList : *->*[Ov]#λ](ov: L)

MyAlg(Ov(1, 2):: Ov("Hello", 2) :: HNil) //compiles
MyAlg(1 :: HNil)     // won't compile
```

Now you can pass any number of OptimizedVariables, keeping their type.
Then if you need to map over it, you just define polymorphic function (from shapeless) for the types you are gonna use.

Actually, if they are only `Int` or `Double`, you can do

```
case class Ov1(start: Int \/ Double, degree: Double) // \/ from scalaZ
case class MyAlg1(ov: List[Ov1])
```

or even use union types from shapeless (`|v|`) instead of `\/`